# AngularJS: A slow java method is not being called from user interface

Tags: java, javascript, spring, angularjs, rest

**My setup:**

I want to call a java method which accepts a string from UI and returns a JSON String. This method takes 5+ seconds to compute and return the JSON String. This method is not even being called when I use UI to enter as argument: I confirmed this as some files are created locally which are not being created.

**The Setter method:**

```
public void setBrand(String brand) {
this.brand  = AmazonReview.getAmazonReview(this.brand);
  }
```

**The slow method:**

```
public static String getAmazonReview(String s){
...;
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./something.pl com " + id);
...;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("product1", l1);
return obj.toJSONString();
}
```

**The Getter method:**

```
public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
  }
```

**UI Code**

```
angular.module("sprang", ["sprang.services"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/brands', {templateUrl: '/views/brands/list.html', controller: BrandListController})
            .when('/brands/:brandId', {templateUrl: '/views/brands/detail.html', controller: BrandDetailController});
    });

function BrandListController($scope, Brand) {
        $scope.brands = Brand.query();
        $scope.deleteBrand = function(brand) {
            brand.$delete(function() {
                $scope.brands.splice($scope.brands.indexOf(brand),1);
                toastr.success("Deleted");
            });
        }
    }

function BrandDetailController($scope, $routeParams, $location, Brand) {
        var brandId = $routeParams.brandId;
        if (brandId === 'new') {
            $scope.brand = new Brand();
        } else {
            $scope.brand = Brand.get({brandId: brandId});
        }
        $scope.save = function () {
            if ($scope.brand.isNew()) {
                $scope.brand.$save(function (brand, headers) {
                    toastr.success("Created");
                    var location = headers('Location');
                    var id = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    $location.path('/brands/' + id);
                });
            } else {
                $scope.brand.$update(function() {
                    toastr.success("Updated");
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

**Problem:**

If I replace the method code with just `return "Hello";` my UI is displaying `Hello`.
My project is setup with AngularJS with Spring which is working fine end to end.
I tried to make the method save the json locally so UI is nomore obliged to display the output, still method is not even called.
How can I proceed further? Thanks in advance.

In simple words, When I call my slow java method in eclipse, I get the expected JSON but when I do the same with UI (AngularJS), the method is not being called.

Comment: Could you show the UI code that is not working?

Comment: My Q now contains UI code.